# PostGIS SQL nested query

Tags: postgis

I have a layer of AIS points that I want to make into lines using st_makeline and then use st_intersects to determine if any of the lines intersect a polygon.

So I think I want to nest

```
st_intersects(st_makeline, polgon.geom)
```

The SQL I am using for the makeline is:

```
SELECT mmsi, ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY date_time_stamp) As newgeom
    FROM ais.cargo As ais
    GROUP BY mmsi;
```

How do I wrap the st_intersects around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single and simple polygon geometry:

```
WITH lines AS (
    SELECT mmsi, ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY date_time_stamp) As newgeom
        FROM ais.cargo As ais
        GROUP BY mmsi
)
SELECT mmsi FROM lines
    WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, ...))', EPSG), newgeom);
```

Substitute the coordinates of your polygon into *x1 y1, x2 y2, ...*, the *EPSG* is the EPSG code of the used projection.

If your polygon(s) are stored in a table called *po* and *geom* column contains the geometry of the polygons:

```
WITH lines AS (
    SELECT mmsi, ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY date_time_stamp) As newgeom
        FROM ais.cargo As ais
        GROUP BY mmsi
)
SELECT mmsi FROM lines INNER JOIN po ON ST_Intersects(lines.newgeom, po.geom);
```

Note 1: I supposed the two geometries are in the same spatial reference system (projection).

Note 2: I used CTE (Common Table Expression) to make query more readable